# VueDatePicker Как менять значение placeholder при выборе даты?

Tags: vue.js, vue3, datepicker

Помогите, пожалуйста, взял первую попавшуюся [библиотеку datapicker](https://vue3datepicker.com/) под Vue3
Написал вот такой код для данного компонента.

```
<template>
        <VueDatePicker
            class="datetimepicker"
            v-model="date"
            :placeholder="getFormattedPlaceholder()"
            @change="onDateChange"
        />
   
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import format from 'date-fns/format';

import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';

export default {
  components: { VueDatePicker },
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      placeholderText: 'Start Date',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(dateString) {
      const date = new Date(dateString);
      return format(date, 'MMMM d, yyyy');
    },
    getFormattedPlaceholder() {
      return this.date ? this.formatDate(this.date) : this.placeholderText;
    },
    onDateChange() {
      // Дополнительные действия при изменении даты, если нужно
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

На выходе, хочу что б когда пользователь в датапикере выбирал дату, она ему отображалась в нормальном формате (format(date, 'MMMM d, yyyy');).
Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста где я делаю ошибку? В `html` коде, я вижу одно, а выводит мне совершенно другое...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: К чему этот пример ? Вопрос не про форматирование даты, он про - почему Vue не отображает отформатированый результат... у меня проблема с логикой работы фремворка... не понимаю, почему идет не то отображение которое ожидаю.

Comment: Сделайте свое форматирование в соответствии с VueDatePicker  - https://vue3datepicker.com/props/formatting/

Comment: И когда у вас в Input есть значение - то Placeholder и не показывается - и зачем он вам, если можете показывать выбранную дату в своем формате.

Comment: Куда именно показываеться выбраное значение ? Я добавил как вы предложили метод `format(date) {
      return format(date, 'MMMM d, yyyy', { locale: this.da });
    },` но он по сути делает тоже самое... Placeholder меняеться, то я это значение не наблюдаю... Что это за атрибут у данного компонента, который отвечает за отображение ?

Comment: Фактически вы выбираете значение Input которое привязано v-model. И конечно никакого placeholder в нем и не покажет когда в date есть значение, Поэтому сделайте как в инструкции для Date. 
<VueDatePicker v-model="date" :format="format"  placeholder="....What you want???...."/>

Comment: У меня например используется:
                  <VueDatePicker class="col"  @update:model-value="isChange = true" v-model="newForm['time']"  placeholder="Выбрать период ..."  range
                                 :transitions="true" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" cancel-text="Отмена" select-text="Выбрать" locale="ru"
                  ></VueDatePicker>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то столкнеться с такой же проблемой, то реализация отображения данного "атрибута" описана [тут](https://vue3datepicker.com/slots/trigger-and-input/). Как написано выше, после выбора даты `placeholder` не отображаеться, а компонент показывает черт знает что (Точнее я не понял где найти это в DOM дереве). Готовый результат выглядит так.

```
<template>
 <VueDatePicker
            class="datetimepicker"
            v-model="date"
            :preview-format="format"
        >
          <template #trigger>
            <p class="clickable-text">{{getFormattedPlaceholder()}}</p>
          </template>
        </VueDatePicker>
</template>
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import format from 'date-fns/format';

import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';
import {da} from "date-fns/locale";

export default {
  components: { VueDatePicker},
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      placeholderText: 'Start Date',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    formatDate(dateString) {
      const date = new Date(dateString);
      return format(date, 'MMMM d, yyyy');
    },

    format(date) {return format(date, 'MMM d, yyyy', { locale: this.da }); },

    getFormattedPlaceholder() {
      return this.date ? this.format(this.date) : this.placeholderText;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```